# Android application intent data passing very slow

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

I am making an application for word practicing. When application starts, I load words from file in raw folder and then pass it with intent to another activity, when user clicks button. On my emulator it has normal speed (its slower then I would expect). But when I run this on my phone, its veery slow when changing the activity with the intent. Notice, that the data I am passing are around 27kb right now. How can I make it faster? I tried loading files every time when i change activity, but its not much faster, than passing it with intent, i also tried multithreaded loading, but didnt notice any improvement.

Comment: Define slow, please? It would be nice if you could add a screen recording and share it here via streamable.com.

Comment: how are you passing the data? is it serializable or parcelable?

Comment: Its just intent.putExtra("..", string);